# How to make that one span goes to the next line in the same div?

Tags: html, css, image, class

This is my first question here and this is also one of my first codes ever so please be understanding :D

I need to create something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mH18n.png.

I don't know what I can do to make span class="price" to the next line. This is still in the same line with class="annual".

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="priceinfo">
        <img src="order-summary-component-main/images/icon-music.svg" />
        <span class="annual">Annual plan</span>
        <span class="price">&#x24; 59.99/year</span>
        <a class="change" href="">Change</a>
</div>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
.priceinfo {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Do you have any ideas what I did wrong and what can I correct?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can wrap both of your spans in a div with display:'flex' and set its direction to column:

```html
<div class="priceinfo">
        <img src="order-summary-component-main/images/icon-music.svg" />
        <div class='price'>
           <span class="annual">Annual plan</span>
           <span class="price">&#x24; 59.99/year</span>
        </div>
        <a class="change" href="">Change</a>
</div>
```

and CSS file:

```css
.priceinfo {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
.price {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a line break (`<br/>`) after each span:

```html
<div class="priceinfo">
        <img src="order-summary-component-main/images/icon-music.svg" />
        <span class="annual">Annual plan</span><br/>
        <span class="price">&#x24; 59.99/year</span><br/>
        <a class="change" href="">Change</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi! I have tried this already (it was my first idea) but the second span is still in the same line as the first one :(